# Multisite Create Site not working

Tags: multisite, htaccess, wp-config, xampp

I've followed multiple Questions, but can't seem be to be able to find a solution.

I'm looking to be able to have a local install multisite, (XAMPP), and succeeded in making multisite available. Network admin seems to work fine, and original site works fine as well..

--(though i'd rather not have to permalink "site.domain.com" because of some settings thing?)

My issue however, is that I go to create a new site from the network admin menu, and once created, when I go to "Visit Dashboard" or "Edit Site" the page times out, and I get a sad face/broken page icon...

> [This webpage is not available
>
> ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT]

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!!

Answer (score 0):

That's not possible with the default xampp. Windows can't work with the wildcard subdomains. 
The easiest way, that you switch to folder, directory structure.

Alternative should help [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7998998/730125) with the customization of the vhost.

Comment: I have xampp on my Mac..

Comment: Xampp is for x. Systems, Windows. Maybe you try Mampp.

Comment: I tried Mampp on my Mac running 10.6.8 snow leopard and for some reason I get an sh error.

Comment: The single page wordpress works just fine.. Just not the multisite

Comment: I think is a host topic, but on Mac I haven't knowhow. Maybe you switch to directory URLs, easier. For testing on local is not a problem to work without subdomains.